# Auto increment data on submit in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, auto-increment

I'm building a small CodeIgniter CRUD application, a very basic one to be precise. Now, in my application, I need to auto increment `roll` data whenever I insert a new student in the following way:

```
    20141001
    20141002
      ...
      ...
    20141099
    20141100
    20142001
    20142002
      ... 
      ...
      ...
    20145099
    20145100
    20151001
    20151002
      ...
      ...
    20151100
    20152001
      ...
      ...
```

And so on.
My controller - `student.php`:

```
    <?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')){ exit('No direct script access allowed');}
    class Student extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            #$this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->model('student_model');
        }

        //Show all Students
        public function index()
        {
            $data['student_list'] = $this->student_model->get_all_students();
           $this->load->view('student_view', $data);
        }


       //Insert a student
       public function insert_student_db()
       { 
            $sdata['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            //Auto-increment, auto-generate roll, for each entry
            $sdata['roll'] = '20141000';
            for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
            {
                $sdata['roll']++;
                if(substr($sdata['roll'], 5) == '100')
                {
                    continue;
                }
            } 
            $sdata['department'] = $this->input->post('department');
            $sdata['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            $sdata['mobile'] = $this->input->post('mobile');
            $res = $this->student_model->insert_student($sdata);
            if($res)
            {
                header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/student/".$this->index());

            }

        }

    }
    ?>
```

My model - `student_model.php`:

```
<?php
class Student_model extends CI_Model 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }   

    //To retrieve all students
    public function get_all_students()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('student');
        return $query->result();
    }

    //To add a new student to the database
    public function insert_student($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('student', $data);
    }

}
?>
```

And it gives me weird results - instead of incrementing, all my entries are assigned one single roll, which is `20141008`

Screenshot of the problematic output I'm getting: 
[image: Screenshot]

My table is `student`, which has the following structure:

```
name             varchar(30)
roll             varchar(10)
department       varchar(10)
email            varchar(50)
mobile           varchar(15)
```

Please note that `roll` is not a Primary Key column, and it's not unique.

How can I solve my problem in context of CodeIgniter?

Comment: show your model and complete controller code!!

Comment: Please share your code relates to DB

Comment: @All I've edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
$sdata['roll'] = '20141000';
for($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
{
    $sdata['roll']++;
    if(substr($sdata['roll'], 5) == '100')
    {
      continue;
    }
}
```

in the line `$sdata['roll'] = '20141000';`  this should be dynamic as everytime when this function is getting call its doing the same thing.

Solution: You can do like Fetch the last roll inserted in db and do +1 to that roll.

Comment: this is just an accident waiting to happen. you need DB locks.

Comment: @Naincy your solution is not clear to me, however I now understand where the problem is. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @CrescentMoon: then my given -1 to me :(

Comment: @NaincyGupta: it was me, and it was because you've created a race condition (well, actually the OP created it, you just blindly ignore it).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to increase in the database you can do this

```
public function incrementByOne($id){
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->set('roll','roll + 1', FALSE);
        $this->db->update('mytable');
    }
```

Comment: -1. I don't have an id column in my table, nor do I have any $id variable. You should go through my question again, have a good look at the controller and `student` table structure.